# Can a Z-Test of Two Sample means in Excel be used to answer two separate hypotheses

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Can a Z-Test of Two Sample means in Excel be used to answer two separate hypotheses.

1) Hypothesized Mean Difference=0 (Two-Tailed) (NULL vs Alternate, ho = ha)

2) Treatment > Control (One-Tailed)

I am currently doing a Z-Test of Two Sample Means (Control vs Treatment) with Null and Alternate Hypotheses. This is used to determine if there is statistical evidence to indicate a difference between the two means using the Two Tail approach.

Question 1
Can I use the same Z-Test of Two Sample Means output from Excel to Answer Hypothesis 2 above ie Treatment > Control based on z Critical one-tail value as I would use in the t-test.?

OR is a t-Test: Two-Sample Assuming Equal Variances the more valid approach.?

Question 2 (lower priority but my samples may vary)
Does it matter if the sample populations vary e.g. n=100 (Treatment) vs n=50 (Control) with either tested hypothesis?

[image: Sample Excel Output of Both Tests using Same Data]

[image]

Comment: Apart from your questions I doubt that you are using the right test. I assume that you do not know the exact variance of these two groups, z-test is therefore not appropriate. Also it seems that you do not have equal variances. I would rather look at Welch's t-test.

Comment: @peteR Thankyou for the feedback Pete..
I am calculating variance from the data using var.p() in excel then using those values in the ZTest Dialog box.

Essentially I am needing to know if it is valid to use the one Z test to do a 1 and 2 tailed hypothesis.   

2 Tail for Mean based Dif  (H_0 ∶ μ_1= μ_2    vs    H_A ∶ μ_1≠μ_2 )
1 Tail for GT/LT Diff   (H_0 ∶ μ_1  ≤ μ_2    vs    H_A ∶ μ_1>μ_2  )

n=same for both samples

In this way I dump the T test and just use the 1 Z Test to answer both

My Sample Accept Reject for Hypothesis 2 in next comment

Comment: @peteR My Statements for the outcome;  The TTest yields the ALMOST the exact same values and outcome as the ZTest

ACCEPT
The NULL hypothesis was NOT rejected since the z-Stat (3.335452444) was LESS than the Z Critical one-tail value of 1.644853627.   There was significant evidence at the 99% confidence level (p-Value < 0.01) to ACCEPT the NULL hypothesis that the Control trial outperformed the Treatment.

Comment: @peteR 

REJECT
The NULL hypothesis was rejected since the z-Stat (3.335452444) was GREATER than the Z Critical one-tail value of 1.644853627.   There was significant evidence at the 99% confidence level (p-Value < 0.01) to REJECT the NULL hypothesis and accept the Alternate hypothesis that the Treatment outperformed the Control.

Comment: Yes you are able to use the same test for multiple hypothesis. But try the welch t-test and check if it is still significant, because z-test assumes a strict normal distribution in your data which will very likely not be the case so it might bias your result.

Comment: @peteR Can you please comment on the validity of the hypotheses and outcome as interpreted from the test result table IMAGE above. I understand the welch test may be more beneficial but I have already declared unequal variance in this test and am aiming to identify 1 or 3 possible and statistically valid outcomes.  Or is what I have presented totally invalid as an approach?

Comment: As I already said. Your tests are probably not really suitable and performing welch test takes a blink of a second so you should definitely do that. Other than that your interpretation seems okay, but be aware: we do not accept the alternative hyptohesis, we just reject or accept the null hypothesis. In the first alternative hypothesis you have a smaller or equal sign but it should be just a smaller sign.

Comment: @peteR Thanks for your help Pete. I have implemented the use of Welch's and it is working fine. I made it into a spreadsheet that allows the pasting of the two fields of data and then the sheet does all the stats and outputs the relevant hypothesis that pertain to the outcome.  Top Job! Cheers Aaron